# How do i make a 2 dimensional scatter plot in R witht he 3rd dimension representing a color spectrum reflecting z values?

Tags: r

I am trying to make a 2 dimensional scatter plot in R with the 3rd dimension representing a color spectrum reflecting values. I have been working on this for 2 weeks and no blogs have helped.  Here is my dataset:

```
x=c(0,0,0,0,264,330,594,726,825,825,2145,2475,3630,5082,8250,10725)
y=c(450,540,2250,630,540,2160,1170,2340,1080,738,540,648,900,900,2340,1152)   
z=c(.017778,0,.079365,.037333,0,0,.052991,0,0,.009259,.048148,0,0,0,.004274,.003472)
```

I have tried this code...

```
jet.colors <-colorRampPalette(c("#00007F", "blue", "#007FFF", "cyan","#7FFF7F", "yellow", "#FF7F00", "red", "#7F0000"))

plot(x,y, col=jet.colors(12)[z], ylim=c(0,100), pch=20, cex=2)

legend(8.5,90, col = jet.colors(12)[z], legend=z, pch=15)
```

... but no points appear when i do so, just a blank xy plane. I have had some success with ggplot2 package but it looks ugly and I want to be able to do it with the simple plot command. I have successfully made 3d graphs from scatterplot3d, wireframe, and countours, but again these are over complicated and ugly Someone please help I know I am missing something simple like perhaps my z values being zeros or less than one.

Comment: A couple of things: first your `ylim` is such that none of your points can be plotted in the selected area (all your `y` values are over 100). Then when you're calling `jet.colors(12)[z]`, `z` is the index yet `z` values being all between 0 and 0.1 can not be used as index. I'm thinking that you should maybe first break your `z` into categories before selecting a color.

Comment: In regards to `ggplot2`, are you aware of the options that allow you to heavily customise the appearance of your plot?: https://github.com/hadley/ggplot2/wiki/-opts()-List
There are also a couple of themes: https://github.com/hadley/ggplot2/wiki/Themes

Answer (score 3):

I don't really know how to explain it except that `cut` will work here.  It turns your numeric variable into a factor and then it works.  PS ggplot2 IMHO, is beautiful and perhaps you're not using it correctly (It's pretty darn flexible):

```
plot(x,y, col=jet.colors(12)[cut(z, 12)], pch=20, cex=2)
```

**EDIT:** I think I can explain it and I see plannapus attempted it already.  When you used the `[]` notation you're indexing.  Indexing needs an integer input but you supplied a continuous input.  By turning it into a factor you give it integer properties (sorry for the butchering of the explanation but this is R according to a non programmer).  You can see this demonstrated below:

```
> jet.colors(12)[cut(z, 12)]
 [1] "#0039FF" "#00007F" "#7F0000" "#50FFAD" "#00007F" "#00007F" "#FF9600" "#00007F" "#00007F" "#0000DC"
[11] "#FFF300" "#00007F" "#00007F" "#00007F" "#00007F" "#00007F"

> jet.colors(12)[as.numeric(cut(z, 12))]
 [1] "#0039FF" "#00007F" "#7F0000" "#50FFAD" "#00007F" "#00007F" "#FF9600" "#00007F" "#00007F" "#0000DC"
[11] "#FFF300" "#00007F" "#00007F" "#00007F" "#00007F" "#00007F"
```

Notice the output is the same?

Comment: +1 The `cut` solution is particularly elegant: `cut` breaks `z` into categories that are sets: `(-7.94e-05,0.00655] (0.00655,0.0132] (0.0132,0.0198] (0.0198,0.0264] (0.0264,0.0331] ... (0.0728,0.0794]`.  These sets are then treated as factors.. which can be used to index.